# pygame Sprite has no attribute draw

Tags: pygame, python-3.4

I am trying to create a little game using Pygame and Python 3.4.
I have been trying to create a character sprite but, even with the large amount of online tutorials, I have not managed to make my code work properly. I know the window loads up fine by itself, but I don't know why I am getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *


class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,img):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()




pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,750))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello world')
img = pygame.image.load("pixel art\RPGchar.png").convert_alpha()





while True: #game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    player.draw(DISPLAYSURF)
    player.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Any help would make me most grateful.
tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that Pygame is only officially supported up to Python 3.3.

You might be able to tweak things so that it works with version 3.4, but if this is one of your first projects, consider removing python 3.4, then installing Python 3.3 or Python 3.2.

Here is the link for Python 3.2.5: https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.2.5

Make SURE you use the 32-bit version!

Then, you can go here: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads to download your pygame package.